# How can i make element both draggable and resizable in jquery?

Tags: jquery

How can i make element both draggable and resizable in jquery?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

both draggable and resizable supports chaining mode so you can simplify your code in one line.
Let say you have a div and id of that div is header which you want to make draggable and resizable.then jquery will work like this....

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#header").draggable().resizable();
 });
```

see demo here...[DEMO](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/jquery-resize-drag/)
refer this tutorial for more information ....[Draggable and resizable](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/01/jquery-resizable-draggable-resize-drag-tutorial-example.html)

Comment: add this jQuery UI...in your file.. http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js
under script tag.

Comment: do we have any alternate library

Answer (score 4):

Besides using jQuery you also have to use jQuery UI http://jqueryui.com/demos/.

jQuery UI will provide all of the functionality for what you would need. More specifically you want the `Draggable` and `Resizable` plugins (perhaps the Droppable too depending of what you are trying to do).

Then you will need to do the following to make it Draggable and Resizable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".elements").draggable().resizable();
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

this is the original [source](http://aleembawany.com/2009/01/25/jquery-resizable-draggable-bug-workaround/)

```
// this will make <div id="box"> resizable and draggable 
$('#box').resizable().parent().draggable(); 

// same but slightly safer since it checks parent's class 
$('#box').resizable().parent('.ui-wrapper').draggable();
```

Answer (score 0):

This two functions are draggable + resizable !

```
    $(function() {
        $("#resizable").resizable({
            containment: "parent"
        });
        $("#resizable").draggable({
            containment: "parent"
        });
    });
```