# Div cutting off the select options

Tags: html, css, select, overflow, auto

I have a div with an overflow: auto set to it(it needs to be "auto").
but when I try to expand the select options inside the div does not expand together, so we cannot see the options.

thanks for helping me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeeU7.png)

Comment: Please post a [example].

Comment: Hi Kameron, thanks for trying to help me out. I have added a pic.

Comment: without showing any of your code how do you expect anyone to be able to help you.  THINK, it's not that hard.  show your code. Pictures are just about worthless

Comment: In order for us to give you the best solution possible, you will have to add the code in a snippet for us to help out. It's impossible for us to debug the screenshot, as helpful as it may be to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to expand a div in the browser by dragging it with mouse? div cannot be expanded like that.

If that is the case, your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825436/how-can-i-make-element-both-draggable-and-resizable-in-jquery)

Comment: here is the code

Comment: I don't see any code....

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-moore-rxm332?file=/src/App.js